# Put string into key value array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string

Hi I got the following string:

```
info:infotext,
dimensions:dimensionstext
```

and i need to put these values into an array in PHP. What is the regex function to put these into an array. I studied the regex codes but it's kinds confusing to me.

I want to put the info as the key and he infotext as the value into an array like this:

```
Array {

[info] => infotext
[dimensions] => dimensionstext

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo here](https://eval.in/761752)

```
<?php
$string ='info:infotext,
dimensions:dimensionstext';
$array = array_map(function($v){return explode(':', trim($v));}, explode(',', $string));   
foreach($array as $v)
{
  $o[$v[0]] = $v[1];
}
print_r($o);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_chunk and array_combine

```
    <?php
    $input  = 'info:infotext,
    dimensions:dimensionstext';

    $chunks = array_chunk(preg_split('/(:|,)/', $input), 2);
    $result = array_combine(array_column($chunks, 0), array_column($chunks, 1));

    print_r($result);
```

http://ideone.com/dRtref